# How to unschedule a trigger for a job in quartz scheduler in Java?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to unschedule a trigger for a particular job I created in Quartz. I have an Email Job which has an associated trigger which is scheduled to be run after two hours. The `jobGroup` and `jobName` are available to me. The `jobName`/`jobId` is "28d5f25e-0669-4570-bdb2-b4e865fcdc02" while the `jobGroup` is "email-jobs". The trigger key also seems to be correct.

```java
String jobName = cancelEmailScheheduleRequest.get("jobName"); //correct
String jobGroup = cancelEmailScheheduleRequest.get("jobGroup"); //correct jobGroup
TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey(jobName, jobGroup); // returns object {name: "4dc25e67-10fa-4e2b-8ca0-c91c024a9a05", group: "email-jobs"}
Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
try {
    if (scheduler.checkExists(triggerKey)) { //returns false instead of true
        scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey);
        response.put("message", "Email Unscheduled");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } else {
        response.put("message", "No such Email to  Unschedule");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.put("message", "Some Error occurred");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

But the line `scheduler.checkExists(triggerKey)` returns `FALSE` while it is supposed to return true and thus my trigger does not get unscheduled. Thus else condition is executed and the returned message is `No such Email to Unschedule`.

Answer (score 0):

`scheduler.checkExists(triggerKey)` will return false as you are putting Job name and Job group to get the trigger key. You need to use the trigger name and trigger group for getting the triggerKey.